# Strings concatenation in Spark SQL query

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm experimenting with Spark and Spark SQL and I need to concatenate a value at the beginning of a string field that I retrieve as output from a select (with a join) like the following:

```
val result = sim.as('s)   
    .join(
        event.as('e),
        Inner,
        Option("s.codeA".attr === "e.codeA".attr))   
    .select("1"+"s.codeA".attr, "e.name".attr)
```

Let's say my tables contain:

**sim**:

```
codeA,codeB
0001,abcd
0002,efgh
```

**events**:

```
codeA,name
0001,freddie
0002,mercury
```

And I would want as output:

```
10001,freddie
10002,mercury
```

In SQL or HiveQL I know I have the `concat` function available, but [it seems](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/SqlParser.scala) Spark SQL doesn't support this feature. Can somebody suggest me a workaround for my issue?

Thank you.

***Note***:
I'm using *Language Integrated Queries* but I could use just a "standard" Spark SQL query, in case of eventual solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate columns in apache spark dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450846/concatenate-columns-in-apache-spark-dataframe)

Comment: I think you don't need to do much of work like using map and creating function.just use this "val result = sim.as("s").join(events, sim("codeA")===events("codeA"),"inner") .select("s.codeA","name").withColumn("codeA",concat(lit("1"),lit(""),col("codeA"))).show
"

Answer (score 0):

The output you add in the end does not seem to be part of your selection, or your SQL logic, if I understand correctly. Why don't you proceed by formatting the output stream as a further step ?

```
val results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT s.codeA, e.code FROM foobar")
results.map(t => "1" + t(0), t(1)).collect()
```

Comment: Hi @huitseeker, thanks for your answer. Your solution might be actually an option, since I have to format the output as tab separated values, indeed.

However, the issue is still valide, since I also need to perform another join with the "concatenated-value", i.e. something like:

`Option("s.codeA".attr === 1+"r.codeA".attr)`

where r has codeA values like 10001, 10002, ...

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively easy to implement new `Expression` types directly in your project. Here's what I'm using:

```scala
case class Concat(children: Expression*) extends Expression {
  override type EvaluatedType = String

  override def foldable: Boolean = children.forall(_.foldable)
  def nullable: Boolean = children.exists(_.nullable)
  def dataType: DataType = StringType

  def eval(input: Row = null): EvaluatedType = {
    children.map(_.eval(input)).mkString
  }
}

val result = sim.as('s)
    .join(
        event.as('e),
        Inner,
        Option("s.codeA".attr === "e.codeA".attr))
    .select(Concat("1", "s.codeA".attr), "e.name".attr)
```