# Concatenate columns in Apache Spark DataFrame

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How do we concatenate two columns in an Apache Spark DataFrame?
Is there any function in Spark SQL which we can use?

Answer (score 234):

With raw SQL you can use `CONCAT`:

- In Python

  ```py
  df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("foo", 1), ("bar", 2)], ("k", "v"))
  df.registerTempTable("df")
  sqlContext.sql("SELECT CONCAT(k, ' ',  v) FROM df")
  ```
- In Scala

  ```scala
  import sqlContext.implicits._

  val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("foo", 1), ("bar", 2))).toDF("k", "v")
  df.registerTempTable("df")
  sqlContext.sql("SELECT CONCAT(k, ' ',  v) FROM df")
  ```

Since Spark 1.5.0 you can use `concat` function with DataFrame API:

- In Python :

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit

  df.select(concat(col("k"), lit(" "), col("v")))
  ```
- In Scala :

  ```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{concat, lit}

  df.select(concat($"k", lit(" "), $"v"))
  ```

There is also `concat_ws` function which takes a string separator as the first argument.

Comment: Use `concat_ws()` to treat **null values** (c.f. below answers).

Answer (score 65):

Here's how you can do custom naming

```python
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlc = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlc.createDataFrame([('row11','row12'), ('row21','row22')], ['colname1', 'colname2'])
df.show()
```

gives,

```python
+--------+--------+
|colname1|colname2|
+--------+--------+
|   row11|   row12|
|   row21|   row22|
+--------+--------+
```

create new column by concatenating:

```python
df = df.withColumn('joined_column', 
                    sf.concat(sf.col('colname1'),sf.lit('_'), sf.col('colname2')))
df.show()

+--------+--------+-------------+
|colname1|colname2|joined_column|
+--------+--------+-------------+
|   row11|   row12|  row11_row12|
|   row21|   row22|  row21_row22|
+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: `lit` creates a column of `_`

Answer (score 41):

One option to concatenate string columns in Spark Scala is using `concat`.

It is necessary to **check for null values**. Because if one of the columns is null, the result will be null even if one of the other columns do have information.

Using `concat` and `withColumn`:

```
val newDf =
  df.withColumn(
    "NEW_COLUMN",
    concat(
      when(col("COL1").isNotNull, col("COL1")).otherwise(lit("null")),
      when(col("COL2").isNotNull, col("COL2")).otherwise(lit("null"))))
```

Using `concat` and `select`:

```
val newDf = df.selectExpr("concat(nvl(COL1, ''), nvl(COL2, '')) as NEW_COLUMN")
```

With both approaches you will have a NEW_COLUMN which value is a concatenation of the columns: COL1 and COL2  from your original df.

Comment: I tried your method in pyspark but it did not work, warning "col should be Column".

Comment: @Samson sorry, I only checked for the Scala API

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre If you are using `concat_ws` instead of `concat`, you can avoid checking for NULL.

Answer (score 28):

### concat(*cols)

**v1.5 and higher**

Concatenates multiple input columns together into a single column. The function works with strings, binary and compatible array columns.

Eg: `new_df = df.select(concat(df.a, df.b, df.c))`

---

### concat_ws(sep, *cols)

**v1.5 and higher**

Similar to `concat` but uses the specified separator.

Eg: `new_df = df.select(concat_ws('-', df.col1, df.col2))`

---

### map_concat(*cols)

**v2.4 and higher**

Used to concat maps, returns the union of all the given maps.

Eg: `new_df = df.select(map_concat("map1", "map2"))`

---

Using [concat](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/pipepipesign.html) operator (`||`):

**v2.3 and higher**

Eg: `df = spark.sql("select col_a || col_b || col_c as abc from table_x")`

Reference: [Spark sql doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

Answer (score 18):

If you want to do it using DF, you could use a udf to add a new column based on existing columns.

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
case class MyDf(col1: String, col2: String)

//here is our dataframe
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
    Array(MyDf("A", "B"), MyDf("C", "D"), MyDf("E", "F"))
))

//Define a udf to concatenate two passed in string values
val getConcatenated = udf( (first: String, second: String) => { first + " " + second } )

//use withColumn method to add a new column called newColName
df.withColumn("newColName", getConcatenated($"col1", $"col2")).select("newColName", "col1", "col2").show()
```

Answer (score 13):

From Spark 2.3([SPARK-22771](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22771)) Spark SQL supports the concatenation operator `||`.

For example;

```
val df = spark.sql("select _c1 || _c2 as concat_column from <table_name>")
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is another way of doing this for pyspark:

```python
#import concat and lit functions from pyspark.sql.functions 
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, lit

#Create your data frame
countryDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Ethiopia',), ('Kenya',), ('Uganda',), ('Rwanda',)], ['East Africa'])

#Use select, concat, and lit functions to do the concatenation
personDF = countryDF.select(concat(countryDF['East Africa'], lit('n')).alias('East African'))

#Show the new data frame
personDF.show()

----------RESULT-------------------------

84
+------------+
|East African|
+------------+
|   Ethiopian|
|      Kenyan|
|     Ugandan|
|     Rwandan|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a suggestion for when you don't know the number or name of the columns in the Dataframe.

```
val dfResults = dfSource.select(concat_ws(",",dfSource.columns.map(c => col(c)): _*))
```

Answer (score 3):

Do we have java syntax corresponding to below process

```
val dfResults = dfSource.select(concat_ws(",",dfSource.columns.map(c => col(c)): _*))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 2.3.0, you may do:

```
spark.sql( """ select '1' || column_a from table_a """)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can do this to concatenate multiple columns. The sample code is to provide you a scenario and how to use it for better understanding.

```
SparkSession spark = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(rdd.context().getConf());
Dataset<Row> reducedInventory = spark.sql("select * from table_name")
                        .withColumn("concatenatedCol",
                                concat(col("col1"), lit("_"), col("col2"), lit("_"), col("col3")));


class JavaSparkSessionSingleton {
    private static transient SparkSession instance = null;

    public static SparkSession getInstance(SparkConf sparkConf) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf)
                    .getOrCreate();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The above code concatenated col1,col2,col3 seperated by "_" to create a column with name "concatenatedCol".

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted a ***Pipe-'I'*** delimited row.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(F.concat_ws('|','_c1','_c2','_c3','_c4')).show()
```

This worked well like a hot knife over butter.

Answer (score 1):

use concat method like this:

```
Dataset<Row> DF2 = DF1
            .withColumn("NEW_COLUMN",concat(col("ADDR1"),col("ADDR2"),col("ADDR3"))).as("NEW_COLUMN")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in pySpark using sqlContext...

```
#Suppose we have a dataframe:
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('row1_1','row1_2')], ['colname1', 'colname2'])

# Now we can concatenate columns and assign the new column a name 
df = df.select(concat(df.colname1, df.colname2).alias('joined_colname'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there are some beautiful inbuilt abstractions for you to accomplish your concatenation without the need to implement a custom function. Since you mentioned Spark SQL, so I am guessing you are trying to pass it as a declarative command through spark.sql(). If so, you can accomplish in a straight forward manner passing SQL command like: 
`SELECT CONCAT(col1, '<delimiter>', col2, ...) AS concat_column_name FROM <table_name>;`

Also, from Spark 2.3.0, you can use commands in lines with: 
`SELECT col1 || col2 AS concat_column_name FROM <table_name>;`

Wherein,  is your preferred delimiter (can be empty space as well) and  is the temporary or permanent table you are trying to read from.

Answer (score 0):

We can simple use `SelectExpr` as well.

`df1.selectExpr("*","upper(_2||_3) as new")`

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL provides two built-in functions: **concat** and **concat_ws**.
we use **concat** to merge multiple strings into single string.
**concat_ws** to merge multiple strings into single string with a delimiter/seperator.

Answer (score -2):

```
val newDf =
  df.withColumn(
    "NEW_COLUMN",
    concat(
      when(col("COL1").isNotNull, col("COL1")).otherwise(lit("null")),
      when(col("COL2").isNotNull, col("COL2")).otherwise(lit("null"))))
```

---

Note: For this code to work you need to put the parentheses "()" in the "isNotNull" function. -> The correct one is "isNotNull()".

```
val newDf =
  df.withColumn(
    "NEW_COLUMN",
    concat(
      when(col("COL1").isNotNull(), col("COL1")).otherwise(lit("null")),
      when(col("COL2").isNotNull(), col("COL2")).otherwise(lit("null"))))
```