# Unable to append "Quotes" in write for dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save a dataframe as .csv in spark. It is required to have all fields bounded by "Quotes". Currently, the file is not enclosed by "Quotes".

I am using Spark 2.1.0

**Code :**

```
DataOutputResult.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
option("header", true).
option("inferSchema", false).
option("quoteMode", "ALL").
mode("overwrite").
save(Dataoutputfolder)
```

**Output format(actual) :**

```
Name, Id,Age,Gender

XXX,1,23,Male
```

**Output format (Required) :**

```
"Name", "Id" ," Age" ,"Gender"

"XXX","1","23","Male"
```

**Options I tried so far :**

QuoteMode, Quote in the options during it as file, But with no success.

Comment: Resolved : option("quoteAll", true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`("quote", "all")`, replace `quoteMode` with `quote`

or play with `concat` or `concat_ws`directly on `df` columns and save without `quote - mode`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{concat, lit}

val newDF = df.select(concat($"Name", lit("""), $"Age"))
```

or create own `udf` function to add desired behaviour, pls find more examples in [Concatenate columns in apache spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450846/concatenate-columns-in-apache-spark-dataframe)

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: quote cannot be more than one character

Comment: try `.option("quote", "\u0000")` might be to do with `unicode nulls`

Comment: I still see the issue. Added the option("quote","\u0000")

Comment: I got an error saying that "java.lang.RuntimeException: quote cannot be more than one character" on \u0000 do you know what it means? ".option("header","true").option("quoteAll","true").option("quote","\u0000").mode("overwrite").save("data/file.csv")"

Answer (score 0):

Unable to add as a comment to the above answer, so posting as an answer.
**In Spark 2.3.1, use quoteAll**

```
df1.write.format("csv")
.option("header", true)
.option("quoteAll","true")
.save(Dataoutputfolder)
```

Also, to add to the comment of @Karol Sudol (great answer btw), `.option("quote","\u0000")` will work only if one is using Pyspark with Python 3 which has default encoding as 'utf-8'. A few reported that the option did not work, because they must be using Pyspark with Python 2 whose default encoding is 'ascii'. Therefore the error  `"java.lang.RuntimeException: quote cannot be more than one character"`