# How to reverse and combine string columns in a spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark version 2.4 and I am trying to write a `udf` which should take the values of column `id1` and column `id2` together, and returns the reverse string of it.

For example, my data looks like:

```
+---+---+
|id1|id2|
+---+---+
|  a|one|
|  b|two|
+---+---+
```

the corresponding code is:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['a', 'one'], ['b', 'two']], ['id1', 'id2'])
```

The returned value should be

```
+---+---+----+
|id1|id2| val|
+---+---+----+
|  a|one|enoa|
|  b|two|owtb|
+---+---+----+
```

My code is:

```py
@udf(string)
def reverse_value(value):
  return value[::-1]

df.withColumn('val', reverse_value(lit('id1' + 'id2')))
```

My errors are:

> ```
> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <function 
> reverse_value at 0x0000010E6D860B70> of type <class 'function'>. For
> column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map'
> function.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat

df.withColumn('val', reverse_value(concat(col('id1'), col('id2'))))
```

Explanation:

- `lit` is a literal while you want to refer to individual columns (`col`).
- `Columns` have to be concatenated using `concat` function ([Concatenate columns in Apache Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31450846/11669673))

Additionally it is not clear if argument of `udf` is correct. It should be either:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf
def reverse_value(value):
    ...
```

or

```
@udf("string")
def reverse_value(value):
    ...
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

@udf(StringType())
def reverse_value(value):
    ...
```

Additionally the stacktrace suggests that you have some other problems in your  code, not reproducible with the snippet you've shared - the `reverse_value` seems to return `function`.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by @user11669673](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56665418/5858851) explains what's wrong with your code and how to fix the `udf`. However, you don't need a `udf` for this.

You will achieve [much better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance) by using [`pyspark.sql.functions.reverse`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.reverse):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, reverse
df.withColumn("val", concat(reverse(col("id2")), col("id1"))).show()
#+---+---+----+
#|id1|id2| val|
#+---+---+----+
#|  a|one|enoa|
#|  b|two|owtb|
#+---+---+----+
```