# I want to add a certain url link in spark using python in a table as a new column

Tags: python

I want to add a url link as a new column in a certain table which is derived from the elements in the table.

I have written a certain code but I think I am making a blunder somewhere

```
myTbl = baseTbl.withColumn("automation link", lit("https://", str(tent), ".live.infarma.com/ui/page-sessions/-", str(userid), "/session?gtf=I_90_DAYS&sessionId=" str(startime, endtime, sessionid), sep = "x" "& id=-", str(internalid) "&filtrfilterApplication=", str(applicationid), "&filtrfilterS=1&gf=all"))
```

I am getting an error if I do this

Comment: Thank you @yaho cho for the edit.

Comment: Do you think you can help me with the code? @yaho cho

Comment: I think you are looking a way to concatenate the string together [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450846/concatenate-columns-in-apache-spark-dataframe) a related post