# How to construct a new column based on listwString> in java

Tags: java, sql, string, list, apache-spark

I have a List **list** =["a","b","c"] and i have to add a new column to my dataframe, but first i have to construct it and this column have to be like:

x|y|z|**list**

strings in my list are columns, i mean that i have to construct my request like :

```
SELECT x,y,z, list FROM Dataframe
```

I tried to split strings in the list with

```
String.join("," , list)
```

but it is seen like a singl column not multiple columns

```
Dataset<Row> df= dataframe.withColumn("NewColumn", concat(dataframe.col("x"), lit("|"), dataframe.col("y"),lit("|"), String.join(","list));
```

**Note 1**: the size of my list is editable and the columns too
**Note 2**: i have to call String.join(","list) in my function withColumn, i don't have the choice

the expected result is a dataframe :

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------
  x     y     z     a     b     c     **NewColumn**
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6   val1|val2|val3|val4|val5|val6
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't see how to construct my new column, thank you for your help

Comment: whats your expected output ??

Comment: the expected result is a dataframe (I edited my post)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate columns in Apache Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450846/concatenate-columns-in-apache-spark-dataframe)

Comment: can you post clearly your input data frame with columns and expected data frame and its columns with sample data?

Comment: I edited again my post to clarify some points

Comment: what ```String.join(",",list)``` will do ??

Comment: it will explode my list of strings to use them as columns

Answer (score 0):

Function `concat` will take params of type `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` but you are passing list of type `String`.

You have to convert list of `String` into list of `Column` type and pass those values to `concat`

```
def concat(exprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*): org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

Below code is in scala, You can convert it into java.

```
val list = List("a","b","c")

dataframe.withColumn(
    "NewColumn", 
    concat(
        col("x"), 
        lit("|"), 
        col("y"),
        lit("|"),
        list.map(c => col(c)):_* // I have added this, You may need to convert your list of strings into list of columns, It will work.
    )
);
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't answer my question... the issue is that i can't split the strings in the list and then i will construct my new column

Comment: my expected result is okay but my issue that when i tried to split my list into columns it is seen like a single column not multiple columns